# API data don't display in the select list

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, material-ui, react-tsx

Goal:
Use the api data (from column name) and display it at select list when you doubleclick in the cell for column Role.

Problem:
When I tried retrieving the api data and display it at select list it doesn't work to display it.

This data from api is supposed to display

```
<option>id labore ex et quam laborum</option>", "<option>quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum</option>", "<option>odio adipisci rerum aut animi</option>", "<option>alias odio sit</option>", "<option>vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa</option>", "<option>id labore ex et quam laborum</option>", "<option>quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum</option>", "<option>odio adipisci rerum aut animi</option>", "<option>alias odio sit</option>", "<option>vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa</option>
```

Bu it only shows the hard coded data that is

```
  <option>Back-end Developer</option>
  <option>Front-end Developer</option>
  <option>UX Designer</option>
```

What part of the code am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-shrl5z?file=App.tsx%3AL28

Thank you!

---

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridRenderCellParams,
  GridColDef,
  useGridApiContext,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import axios from 'axios';

function SelectEditInputCell(props: GridRenderCellParams) {
  const { id, value, field } = props;
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = async (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    await apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id,
      field,
      value: event.target.value,
    });
    apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id, field });
  };
  console.log(items);

  return (
    <Select
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      size="small"
      sx={{ height: 1 }}
      native
      autoFocus
    >
      <option>Back-end Developer</option>
      <option>Front-end Developer</option>
      <option>UX Designer</option>
      {items}
    </Select>
  );
}

const renderSelectEditInputCell: GridColDef['renderCell'] = (params) => {
  return <SelectEditInputCell {...params} />;
};

const items: Array<string> = [];

export default function App() {
  axios
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments')
    .then((response) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        let output = response.data[i];
        items.push('<option>' + output.name + '</option>');
      }
    });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}

const columns = [
  {
    field: 'name',
    headerName: 'Name',
    width: 120,
  },
  {
    field: 'role',
    headerName: 'Role',
    renderEditCell: renderSelectEditInputCell,
    editable: true,
    width: 180,
  },
];

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Olivier',
    role: 'Back-end Developerrr',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Danail',
    role: 'UX Designerrrr',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Matheus',
    role: 'Front-end Developerrrr',
  },
];
```

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68584398/13405106). You need to use `MenuItem` component and map you array to create item list. Instead of `items.push('<option>' + output.name + '</option>');` just store api response in items state

Comment: Do you have a sample?

Comment: The above linked answer is working example. You can also check [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) mui example, how they are mapping the options